# Largest Among ten numbers using Arrays

Tags: arrays

What's wrong with my code? It always returns the last number but not the largest? I have spent the last half and hour scratching my head & I still can't find what's wrong here..

Please help

```
// Largest among ten numbers

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int num[10],large,b; // Global Variables
int largest(int a); // Function protype

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d = ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&num[i]);
        large = largest(num[i]); // Calling Function
        /* 
            printf("Num(%d)= %d",i,num[i]); // Testing
            printf("\nLargest for now = %d\n\n",large); //  Testing
        */
    }
    printf("\n\n\n%d is the largest",large);
    getch();
}

int largest(int a) // Function definition
{
    if (a>=b)
        {
            return a;
            b=a;
        }
    else
        {
            return b;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're always comparing the number entered against the constant `0`. What are you trying to do with the `largest` function?

Comment: Okay a silly mistake. I put int b=0 at the top. Now ? what's wrong ? I am comparing the number with the previous number b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (a>=b)
    {
        return a;
        b=a;
    }
```

You return before assigning so b is always 0. Just do the assignment before returning i.e.

```
if (a>=b)
    {
        b=a;
        return a;            
    }
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CBD24603)

Comment: But isn't 'b' already assigned in the first loop?

In the for loop iteration
when i = 0, let's say a=5, then b will be assigned 5.
when i = 1, let's say a=9, but since b is already assigned should it compare 9(a) with b(5) ?

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm new to programming.